# bash: Run multiple command in background, store output in variable

Tags: bash, background-process

How do I run a sequence of commands in parallel, and store their output in a variable?

I've tried:

```
output=`(echo -n "started "; sleep 2; echo "stopped") &`

echo "output before=$output"
wait
echo "output after=$output"
```

And got a pause of two seconds, followed by:

```
output before=started stopped
output after=started stopped
```

I expected:

```
output before=
<2 seconds pause>
output after=started stopped
```

How do I run a sequence of commands in the background, and store their output in a variable?

Comment: All block within `()` is executed on background, so you get its output once everything is finished. Hence, the `sleep` is "hidden" to you.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? This example looks constructed to illustrate an issue that may not be the best way to solve the problem you really have.

Comment: Run ~10 commands in parallel, wait for termination, and process their standard output separately.

Answer (score 6):

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `‘&’`, the shell
>   executes the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as
>   executing the command in the background. The shell does not wait for
>   the command to finish, and the return status is 0 (true).

A workaround would be to store the output in a file and read from it.  The following might work for you:

```
tempout=$(mktemp)
( echo -n "started "; sleep 2; echo "stopped" ) > "${tempout}" &
echo "output before=$(<$tempout)"
wait
echo "output after=$(<$tempout)"
```

Comment: There might be buffering issues involved here, where nothing is available yet to read from `$tempout` when the first `echo` is called. Depending on processor load, the background task may not even be started before the first `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is the evaluation of this line: 

`` output=`(echo -n "started "; sleep 2; echo "stopped") &` ``

Even though you want to put the whole command in the background (and this results in return code 0, as devnull mentioned) - but the result is not known. And to assign value to $output - it has to wait for the original command to exit.

You **did not** put var assignment in the background.

But still @devnull's workaround applies. Instead of files you may use named pipes.